Execute command in shell script not working with dollar sign
I have the below command which works fine when I try to execute via cmd line
s3cmd ls $'bucket/raw_data/filename'
Now , I have lot of file , I try to do the above via shell script, where I take input from a text file.
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -f "$1" ]; then
  echo "Error: Input file not found"
  exit 1
fi

while IFS= read -r line; do
  s3cmd ls $('bucket/raw_data/%s') "$line"
done < "$1"

I get an error saying path not found and also the dollar sign is resolved to my home path for example - /home/hostname. Also, %s is not substituted. Dollar and single quote is needed as I have some special character in names.

$'anything' is the same as 'anything' unless the string has escape sequences. If it has, say, '\t', then that stays two characters starting with a backslash in a regular string, but becomes one character with only a tab if it's written $'\t'. So $'bucket/raw_data/filename' is 100% identical to 'bucket/raw_data/filename' unless your name has weird characters in it.

Mind, $(...) is a completely different thing, and you shouldn't be using it here.

Try that yourself: if [ 'bucket/raw_data/filename' = $'bucket/raw_data/filename' ]; then echo "identical"; else echo "different"; fi -- as long as you're in bash, ksh, zsh, or another shell that supports $'', the output will be identical (and elsewhere I'd expect a syntax error).

...and actually, for your specific case, the quotes are themselves syntax and not actually passed to s3cmd either. Two more cases to test: [ bucket/raw_data/filename = 'bucket/raw_data/filename' ] && echo equal and similarly, [ bucket/raw_data/filename = $'bucket/raw_data/filename' ] && echo equal. You'd need them if your key or bucket name contained spaces or other characters that the shell would otherwise parse as syntax, but even then, you'd need syntactic quotes, not literal ones.

You have to use printf -v in order to prepare a variable:
#!/bin/bash
if [ ! -f "$1" ]; then
    echo "Error: Input file not found"
    exit 1
fi

while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf -v filename 'bucket/raw_data/%s' "$line"
    s3cmd ls "$filename"
done < "$1"


ok .thanks I will try

but dollar sign is not getting preserved. after ls - $'bucket/raw_data/filename'

single quotes is preserved.

I tried backslash the $" $filename"  but does not work

F.Hauri - Give Up Github Can you please check?

@DotNetDev19, the $ isn't supposed to be preserved. It's syntax, not literal data. Anyone or anything that told you otherwise is wrong.

@DotNetDev19, ...now, if $line has escape sequences that need to be transformed into the values they refer to, then you want to change this answer's code to use %b instead of %s -- but you also need to be showing us that as part of your question since it's a key aspect of the requirements.

Note that for simple string interpolation like this, printf -v is overkill -- just use s3cmd ls "bucket/raw_data/$line". If you need to do something fancier (like escape sequence parsing, as Charles Duffy mentioned), then you might need printf.

What are you trying to do with dollar sign? Try by yourself: compare echo $'bucket/raw_data/%s' and echo 'bucket/raw_data/%s'

You can also use xargs. If your filenames are in file and you are not expecting to interpolate values:
xargs -L1 -I% s3cmd ls '"bucket/raw_data/%"' < file


What's with the literal quotes inside the string? I seriously doubt the bucket name starts with " and the key ends with "

I am not familiar with s3, but you command interpolation looks odd :s3cmd ls $('bucket/raw_data/%s') "$line".
I think you should try something like this:
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -f "$1" ]; then
  echo "Error: Input file not found"
  exit 1
fi

while IFS= read -r line; do
  s3cmd ls "bucket/raw_data/$line"
done < "$1"

